# request body empty with POST node js ajax calling with json web token

Tags: jquery, node.js, post, jwt

can you help me~

I am trying to use json webtoken on node js and calling post method to set data.

Code on node js server:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/jwt' }));
```

Code frontend call:

```js
$.ajax({
            url: '/setSession',
            type: 'POST',
            Accept : 'application/json',
            //contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "hello": templateName}, 
            //data: JSON.stringify({ "hello": templateName}), 
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token
            },
            success: function (result) {console.log('post ok'+JSON.stringify(result));
                // CallBack(result);
            },
            error: function (error) { console.log('post failed'+JSON.stringify(error));
         
            }
         });
```

but  req.body when calling post request is empty or {}, I tried bodyparser, or dataType but no success

Answer (score 0):

1) For your server code, this how the implementation should be done :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Books service started on port 4000');
});
```

2) You have to define a middleware to check if it's a valid token or not :

```
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        jwt.verify(token, accessTokenSecret, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.sendStatus(403);
            }

            req.user = user;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};
```

3) Post router :

```
app.post('/setSession', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
   /* your logic here */
});
```